# Webpage Redirect on Apache2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, domain, redirect

I am using Apache 2.4 with ssl, I found lot of solution to redirect domains on Apache, also got solution to redirect to other Sub directory. But here I have some other requirement where I want to redirect from root directory to 6th or 7th Subdirectory.

for eg:
https://www.example.com   reroute to  https://www.example.com/_layouts/15/Indus/corporate/#/home

I want to know the syntax which can help in solving this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual host config file or if you dont separete and hold everything in httpd.conf you mast add Redirect derective like this.

> Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/admin/"

In your case you must redirect root

> "/" to "https://www.example.com/_layouts/15/Indus/corporate/#/home"